# Set telegram webhook in custom module on drupal 8

Tags: telegram, drupal-8, telegram-webhook

I created a module and implemented my Telegram bot code in /src/Controller/BotController.php. Now I want to set a webhook and use     `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setwebhook?url=https://<my-site>/<my-module-path-in-"name.routing.yml">`.

The webhook is set, but my code doesn't work and gives me a 500 error.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

My code:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\telegram\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class TelegramController extends ControllerBase {

public function telegram() {

$update = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);
$chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$message = $update["message"]["text"];

if (isset($chatId) and isset($message)) {
    sendMessage($chatId, $message);
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot504387877:AAFHnQe-AdscpSZN42yY-JYem5jwdJc131Q/sendMessage?chat_id=" . $chatId . "&text=" . $message;
}
file_get_contents($url);

$build['#theme'] = 'new';
return $build;

}

}
```

Comment: Helllooooooooooooo

Answer (score 0):

I think it may cause by unescaped URL, but you need to provide error message to determine.

If you just want to make it done, you can use [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=taipei.sean.telegram.botplayground) Android application. For instance, use `getWebhookInfo` to obtain error reason.

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]